# Inversion in conditional sentence without "were"

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

> I have a nuclear family of five. In fact, I have two sisters and unfortunately
>   no brothers. **If I had at least one brother, the life would be more
>   enjoyable.**

Can I make an inversion in the bold part? Or I can do this only if I have 'were' in my conditional sentences?

For example:

> Were I you, I would forgive him. *(If I were you, I would forgive him.)*

Comment: To say: *Had I one brother.....* sounds very theatrical. You might hear people saying: *had I time* or *had I opportunity* but this is to make a point. It's not everyday speech. By the way *my life* or *life* would be more enjoyable, not *the life*.

Comment: A minor correction: it should be "life would be more enjoyable", with no *the*, because we're talking about a general phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

In present-day English, inverting the subject with *should*, *were* and *had* to express the sense of an *if* clause is still technically 'grammatical':

> Should you find my book (*= If you should find my book*), please send it to me.
>   Were he running (*= If he were running*) he might win.
>   Had she gone (*= If she had gone*) to the interview she would have been hired.

*Had* and *were* may be inverted even when they are not used as auxiliaries:

> Were he here (*= If he were here*), he could show us how to do it.
>   Had I a brother (*= If I had a brother*), life would be more enjoyable.

In **practice**, however, this construction is only found in very formal texts, or in the speech of people trying to sound formal; and even there it has a quaint, old-fashioned ring.

This is "school English": you need to be able to recognize its use in older texts, but there is no reason for you to use it in your own writing or speech.

Comment: I almost understand nothing about your answer. It was not clear to me as I am an intermediate leaner.In the end, I don't know if we could use inversion in my question or not.

Comment: @MickeyMouse I've rewritten -- is it clear now? It's grammatical, but very old-fashioned.

Comment: @MickeyMouse , StoneyB suggests that you *can* but you rarely *should*.  "Had I at least one brother, life would be ..." is grammatical but usually formal.

Comment: @StoneyB : Thanks for great explanation. I fully understand it. My English teacher told:" if we use this kind of structure in our essay, we will score high in IELTS exam." So, we only use 'had','were' and 'should'. If we have any other verb in our conditional sentences, we are not allowed to use 'inversion in conditional sentences". Am i right? For example, "If I lived in United Satetes, I woudn't need to get IELTS certification."

Comment: @MickeyMouse That's right. "Lived I in the US" was OK two or three hundred years ago, but not today!

Comment: @StoneyB: Thanks so much.I really appreciate your help.